# Facebook iOS Login API 2.0 (SDK 3.15.1)

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I'm having an infuriating time with Facebook's 2.0 Login api.  For me (the developer) and the other developers, it works perfectly fine.  But for a couple of users, the Login fails. For the log in process I do:

```
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:self.readPermissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             _self.loginInProcess = NO;
             [_self _setSessionState:status error:error];
         });
     }];
```

Normally, the FB app opens and the user is given the option to accept/deny access.  However, for some users this screen never appears.  Instead, the app is switched away from (like normal) but as soon as it gets to the Facebook App (I think...) it immediately switched back to the source app but the fails without error.  Because I can't replicate the issue on any of my own devices, I can't be certain but it appears that the completion handler is never called.  So the app sits in limbo waiting for the Facebook to approve/deny the request that never comes.

Of note, I have all the correct calls in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    return wasHandled;
}
```

Has anyone dealt with anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out Facebook was returning the correct data.  In order to discover this I had to create a bunch of `UIAlertView`'s, push out a new beta and have one of the users send me screen shots of those alerts so I could see what exactly was going on... about the closest thing to remote debugging I could get on an iPhone.

In the end, it turned out that a KVO I had set up wasn't firing (watching for the login process to complete).  I still have no idea why it wasn't firing.  It worked on 95% of the devices, but I'm working with code from a previous developer that has turned out to have quite a few land-mines in it.  I fixed the problem by creating a block completion handler and using that when the login process was completed.